# Is that possible span inline css hide on all moblie views with Jquery

Tags: javascript

Here Is my Code :

```
<div class="banner-content">

<p><span style="font-size: 18pt; font-family: Roboto, geneva, sans-
serif;">Welcome to Top 5 Psychic Reading Sites</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: roboto, geneva, sans-
serif;">We’ve reviewed and rated the best online psychic reading services. 
Now you can find the right psychic to connect with from the comfort of your 
mobile phone. From love psychics to tarot readings, fortune telling to 
career forecasts, your journey to a brighter future starts now.
</span></p></div>
```

Is it possible to span inline css hide on all mobile views with `Jquery`

Comment: You want to hide them only when accessed via mobile?

Comment: yes , i want to hide when accessed via mobile not in tablets or desktop .

Answer (score 1):

First add the class hideOnMobile to the span, then in your css put:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .hideOnMobile {
        display: none;
    } 
 }
```

This will hide all elements with the class hideOnMobile when the screen is smaller than 1024px, you can play around with the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

First use a simple method to detect a mobile device

```
function isMobile(){ 
   return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Now filter out your `span` to check if anyone of them have `display:inline` and hide them

```
isMobile() && Array.from(document.querySelector( "span" )).forEach( function(ele){
  if (ele.style.display == 'inline')
  {
     ele.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

**Edit**

If you are not able to get the inline property via above code also try ([working fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vuh8sfjx/2/))

```
var propValue = (ele) => window.getComputedStyle(ele).style[prop];
isMobile() && Array.from(document.querySelector( "span" )).forEach( function(ele){
  if (propValue(ele)  == 'inline')
  {
     ele.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

Comment: Note that this only works if `display` is explicitly set.

Comment: @jhpratt `span`s have default display property value as `inline`

Comment: JS doesn't get that though, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuh8sfjx/). By default, nothing is received from `style.display`.

Comment: I've never had the display property unavailable in js when not explicitly set.